# Upgrade bash,but bash --version no change,why

Tags: linux, bash, shellshock-bash-bug

For Shellshock issue
I upgrade bash on redhat 4,5 use the follow steps

1. check bash version

   `root@aaaA:/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64>bash --version`
   `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
   `Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`
2. upgrade bash

   `rpmbuild --rebuild -bb bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.src.rpm`
   `cd /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/`
   `root@aaa:/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64>rpm -Uvh bash-*`
   `Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]`
   `1:bash                   ########################################### [ 50%]`
   `2:bash-debuginfo         ########################################### [100%]`
3. check bash version again

`root@aaa:/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64>bash --version`
`GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
`Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

4. reboot and check bash version again

`root@aaa:/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64>bash --version`
`GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
`Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

5. check rpm

`root@aaa:/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64>rpm -qa | grep bash`
`bash-3.2-33.4`
`bash-debuginfo-3.2-33.4`

Why bash version no change to bash-3.2-33.4

Comment: did the new installation installed newer bash executable to another location that what's in your PATH. do which bash and whereis bash, try bash --version from all those bash executables. if you find a newer one, put that's file's path first in order in $PATH

Comment: `root@aaa:/bin>rpm -qa | grep bash`
`bash-3.2-33.4`
`bash-debuginfo-3.2-33.4`
`root@aaa:/bin>which bash`
`/usr/local/bin/bash`
`root@aaa:/bin>whereis bash`
`bash: /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz`
`root@aaa:/bin>/bin/bash --version`
`GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
`Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`
`root@aaa:/bin>/usr/local/bin/bash --version`
`GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
`Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`
`root@aaa:/bin>`

Comment: `root@aaa:/usr/local>echo $PATH`
`/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin:/root/bin:.:/root/bin`

Comment: see if this helps! https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1207723

Comment: ANS.That's normal. Red Hat usually backports the fix to the existing version. bash -version will not show any difference in the output post update.